# Stop the automated messages coming from Facebook and receive only messages sent from my server

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

As shown in the screenshots:

1. I have sent a "Hi" message. The first reply I got (Button Template) is from my server. But the second message "Hi Dhruv, welcome back." is from the Facebook server.
2. A quick reply message "Yes" has been sent. The first reply (Generic Template) is from my server. The second reply "Sorry, I did not understand that" is from the Facebook server.

I want to stop the replies from Facebook side.

Screenshot 1:

[image]

Screenshot 2:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Disable Send instant replies to anyone who messages your Page on messaging section